# Prevent other users from deleting my comments in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, collaboration

When using the comment feature present in most Office apps (e.g. right click on a word or sentence and select New Comment) my comment shows up on the right side panel, and others can add subcomments, resolve thread, delete thread, etc.

[image]

How can I lock them so that others can respond or Resolve but not Delete?

(Yes, it's because of that colleague who just deletes comments when he doesn't want to fix the document)

Comment: Have the document in a proper document management system that has version control so that you can see who is simply deleting comments rather than actioning them. Also you could probably record a VBA macro that reinserts the comments automatically so you can simply send him the same document with a comment along the lines of "changes were not actioned, resending. Again."